# Is there any value in reposting someone else's article?

Tags: seo, blog, articles

Say you get permission from the article's author to repost his article on your own site, and give a link back to the original author; is there any SEO value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only benefits the original publishing site and can potentially harm you if you do this incorrectly.

By re-posting the same content as the original site you now have duplicate content. This is something Google does *not* want. To remedy this you have to use canonical URLs. This tells Google that the other site is the original source of the information. This also means the page on your site where this content is published will not be indexed. This obviously is not useful to you. Should you omit the canonical URL you run the risk of having your site penalized up to and including removal from Google's index. I doubt one article will do it. But if you start down this path you don't know when the hammer will drop.

The original publishing website will benefit, however, as the canonical link will essentially tell Google to give that page credit for that content and any links you get to point to that page. So naturally they want you to republish their content.